# Drain height and sloping

Tags: plumbing, drain

(first time posting)

I have no experience in plumbing so thank you for any help! I am trying to install a garbage disposal. I had 3 quick questions!

[image]

1. In the picture above, you can see that my garbage disposal outlet is the same height as the drain. Will this cause issues where water will stay in the garbage disposal?

[image]

2. Because of the P trap I have a slope going towards the drain upwards. My understanding is that this is fine because water will still exit down the drain while there will be quite a lot of water stuck in the pipes under sink. Is this going to cause any issues?
3. You can see I'm using two elbows in the pipeline, on the very left joint I'm not sure how to join them together because it's two female ends against each other with no threads. Do I need to buy a separate product to connect these two?

If there are any other issues with what I"m doing, please let me know!

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work.  You will have water sitting in the bottom of your GD, and the sink will drain slowly.  Three ways to get this to work:

1. Get a low profile disposal—although yours looks pretty short already, so maybe no gains there.
2. Get a shallower sink.
3. Open up the wall and reconnect the drain at a lower point on the in-wall pipe.  This assumes the pipe goes down, and not across to some other stack.

Comment: The sink looks pretty shallow already.  On to #3.   As long as you'll be cutting open the wall you should also clean up the mess there with the cold supply.  Looks like you put a saddle valve piercing the pipe BEHIND the cold supply valve.  For a fridge or filter?  Get rid of that and replace it with a proper valve.

Comment: @jay613 yeah, it's hard to tell how shallow the sink is, with that piece of lumber in the front, and the photo not including the top of the counter.  Also, you're right about the valve—I didn't even notice that mess!

Comment: Thank you!

Yes I'm planning on hiring a plumber to move the drain at a lower point in the pipe. Luckily it is a vertical pipe

Ahh at the same time I might get the plumber to help me with the other connections